# Draw, select and edit a polygon/area

Tags: normals

I am new to Blender and would like to create something similar to the picture. How can I create individual Polygons (marked yellow in the image below) and edit them individually? or select all the other areas as well so that I only have to modulate them on one area and it carries over to the others?

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome! Is this what you are looking for? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/mesh/tissue.html

Comment: You can easily create the original shape with the Tissu addon or just with some Inset Individual and Extrude Faces Along Normals, you'll be able to select all the tips at once with a Select Similar operation and scale them for example, but you won't be able to easily change every tip at once if this edit is too complicated, maybe it's doable with Geometry Nodes?

Comment: thanks so much for your help, i think thats the right way :)